# duplicate post data get using serialize() form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

i have submit form inputs using serialize() function
and i have get post all data in php post
but only multi select drop down post data get duplicate and other input data get in correct format
show below code of ajax form submit

```
 $("form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: hiddenUrl + 'home/edit_employee',
                data: $( ":input" ).serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                datatype:"json",
                success: function (response) {
                // window.location.href = hiddenUrl + "home/listemployee";
                }
            });

        });
```

and get post data in php side
output show below

```
<pre>Array
(
    [id] => 16
    [fname] => abcdestiny
    [lname] => patel
    [empcode] => 44445
    [schoolId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
        )

    [school_id] => 
    [tableInc_length] => 50
)
```

here school id is multi select drop down post value
i have select only 3 option and those value is 2,6,7
but duplicate value same time show below schoolId[] output
why post get same value in two time?

Comment: Can you show your form code? or `schoolId` and `school_id` both are same so use different name for both.

Comment: i serach school_id in html form but thire are no any name found in whole form

Comment: use school_id instead of schoolId in your form and then check.

Comment: blank value get

Comment: you're passing `$( ":input" ).serialize()` so it'll take only inputs value, and your dropdown whould be in select tag. so use `$('form').serialize()` or `$(this).serialize()` instead of `$( ":input" ).serialize()`

Comment: tx @dilip hirapara i used $(this).serialize() instead of $( ":input" ).serialize() and now output get correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `$( ":input" ).serialize()` so it'll take only inputs value, And your dropdown whould be in select tag. so use `$('form').serialize()` or `$(this).serialize()` instead of `$( ":input" ).serialize()`